# push notification in spring mvc REST API for mobile

Tags: android, spring, rest, spring-mvc, push-notification

I am developing a web application project using Spring 4 MVC REST API, where i am used to develop rest calls.

Those rest calls would be used by our UI(WEB,Mobile) team for UI support.

Now, I have an requirement from mobile end that i want to respond to push notification VIA GCM.

Kindly help me out to do that in my application.

Comment: You can respond via resttemplate and you can send out real-time notifications from spring server with cometd.

Comment: can you please help me with any examples or web site

Comment: check out cometd examples....